# Is "well-accomplished" a natural expression?

Tags: meaning

I know that "well" can be placed before a past participle, to increase the extent to which something is acted on. For example, well-preserved, well-known, well-packed..

But when I use some word with very positive meaning themselves, can I put "well" before it? For example, "well-accomplished"?

Comment: Have you checked in [any easily available resources?](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/well-accomplished)

Answer (score 2):

This question addresses two factors:

1. whether the (past-)participial adjective involved is gradable at all
2. if it is, whether well-  may be prefixed to achieve this.

> 1'. Extreme adjectives, participial examples of which include
>
> amazed, astonished, astounded, delighted, devastated, dumbfounded, exasperated, mortified do not normally grade.
>
> 2'. Some PP-adjectives are gradable but not using the well- prefix:
>
> annoyed, bored, confused, crowded, depressed, determined, embarrassed, shocked, surprised (eg very annoyed)

Of course, modern slang / informal usage uses 'well' in novel situations: The family were well amazed when I turned up.

Comment: I'm totally amazed that you were somewhat astounded at my being positively astonished to see you completely exasperated. :)

Comment: Enough to make one well-(:'d.

Comment: Thank you very much, you just say what I want to say in a clearer way. Still I want to ask whether "well-accomplished" is a               good expression.

Comment: I assume you've checked the dictionary reference I gave above, which shows it's acceptable and used. There is the problem that it seems a redundancy: well-accomplished and accomplished are near synonyms. 200 000 hits for "well-accomplished" on Google seem to indicate that it's not uncommon. Personally, I'd use 'an accomplished violinist' but 'well accomplished on the violin'. And please notice that you switch from the particular to the general in going from your title to the main body of your post.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will learn to be more careful and coherent.